# How do I copy a file to my server using scp

Tags: linux, server

I want to copy a file to my server. But, the only port open for ssh is 2232. I am doing the follwing at present, what am I doing wrong.

```
scp -P 2232 -l file.1 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/~
```

Comment: Being on the wrong site, for one thing :) This question is for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Oh, with your `scp`? `-l` expects a number, which `file.1` is not.

Comment: And, you don't especially need to specify the port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp [file_directory][file_name] @[server_ip]:[directory where you want to put the file]` .For example:

`scp example.txt @192.168.3.1:/home/` . Then do as the guide what system gave. I hope this can help you.